# When solving a heavy PDE Mathematica falls out: what can be done

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, memory

I am solving a heavy PDE. The mesh is huge, and Mma falls out after few tens of minutes solving: the cell becomes inactive, kernel (pressumably) quits, all variables turn blue.

My question is, **what could be done with it**?

To be precise, I am solving a problem of a 2D conductivity within a domain with subdomains possessing two different conductivities. In addition the latter differ 10^6 fold from one another.
  Here is a simple example which can be solved quite satisfactorily. In this example the whole domain is 5x5 square with the conductivity 1. There is a disk with the radius 2 with the conductivity 10^6 in the center of this domain.

```
    Clear[sigma, slv];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{r = 2., mcm = 0.05, mqg = 0.6},

 (* Here an external and internal boundaries of the domain are \
created *)
 extBound = {{0, 0}, {0, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 0}};
 intBound = 
  Table[{r*Cos[\[Theta]] + 2.5, r*Sin[\[Theta]] + 2.5}, {\[Theta], 0, 
     2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/20}] // N;
 (* Here are the coordinates of the both boundaries *)
 coordinates = Join[extBound, intBound];

 (* These are the incidents to create the boundary mesh *)
 incidents1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}};
 incidents2 = 
  Join[Drop[
    Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[extBound] + 1, 
      Length[intBound] + Length[extBound]}], -1], {{Length[intBound] +
       Length[extBound], Length[extBound] + 1}}];

 (* This makes the boundary mesh and element mesh *)
 boundaryMesh = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[incidents1], 
     LineElement[incidents2]}];
 elementMesh = 
  ToElementMesh[boundaryMesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{2.5, 2.5}, 1}, {{0.01, 0.01}, 2}}, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1, "MaxCellMeasure" -> mcm, 
   "MeshQualityGoal" -> mqg];

 (* This function fixes the conductivity 10^6, if the marker is 1 and \
1 otherwise *)
 sigma = If[ElementMarker == 1, 1000000, 1];

 (* This solves the the potential u and currents v1 and v2 *)
 slv = NDSolveValue[{D[sigma*D[u[x, y], x], x] + 
       D[sigma*D[u[x, y], y], y] == 0, 
     v2[x, y] == sigma*D[u[x, y], x], v3[x, y] == sigma*D[u[x, y], y],
      DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 5], 
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]}, {u[x, y], v2[x, y], 
     v3[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] elementMesh] // Quiet
 ]
```

This example works nicely. Here is, for example, the y component of the current plotted:

```
    Show[{
  ContourPlot[Evaluate[slv[[3]]], {x, y} \[Element] elementMesh, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Current, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(y\)]\)", 16]],
  elementMesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> EdgeForm[Gray]]],
  boundaryMesh["Wireframe"]
  }, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

I would like to stress that what I have shown above works nicely, and I show it to convince you that the whole approach works.

Now comes the difficult part.

The domain has the form of a trapeze with the bases 0.15 and 0.05 and the height 0.15 and the conductivity 1. It has multiple (about 3000) disks inside with the conductivity 10^6 and the radius 0.0005 each.

This makes the domain consisting of the trapeze with the disks, and defines functions to construct the mesh, if the coordinates of the disks centers are known:

```
 Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Clear[incidents1, coordinates];
incidents1 = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}};
basic = Join[Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, 1, 9}], {{10, 1}}];

coordinates[listOfCenters_List] := 
  Join[extBound, Flatten[intBound[listOfCenters], 1]];

Clear[incTable];
incTable[listOfCenters_List] := 
 Table[Map[Plus[#, {(10*(i - 1) + 4), (10*(i - 1) + 4)}] &, 
   basic], {i, 1, Length[listOfCenters]}]

Clear[lineElement];
lineElement[listOfCenters_List] := 
 Prepend[LineElement /@ incTable[listOfCenters], 
  LineElement[incidents1]]
Clear[boundaryMesh, elementMesh, extBound];

extBound = {{0, 0}, {0.05, 0.15}, {0.1, 0.15}, {0.15, 0}};
Clear[intBound]
single[lst_List] := 
 Drop[Table[{0.0005*Cos[\[Theta]] + lst[[1]], 
     0.0005*Sin[\[Theta]] + lst[[2]]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], 
     2 \[Pi]/10}], -1] // N
intBound[listOfCenters_List] := Map[single, listOfCenters];
coordinates[listOfCenters_List] := 
  Join[extBound, Flatten[intBound[listOfCenters], 1]];

marker1[listOfCenters_List] := 
  Map[ReplaceAll[#, {x_, y_} -> {{x, y}, 1}] &, listOfCenters];
boundaryMesh[listOfCenters_List] := 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates[listOfCenters], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> lineElement[listOfCenters]];
elementMesh[listOfCenters_List] := 
 ToElementMesh[boundaryMesh[listOfCenters], 
  "RegionMarker" -> 
   Join[marker1[listOfCenters], {{{0.01`, 0.01`}, 2}}]]
```

Here one can find a notebook with the list of centers of the disks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/devojhotapad5om/list.nb?dl=0

It is entitled "lst". There are about 3000 disks. With this list one makes the mesh

```
mesh = elementMesh[lst]
```

It is created successfully. Here is an image of a small fragment of this mesh

[image]

If I solve this equation only for the potential:

```
    sigma = If[ElementMarker == 1, 1000000, 1];
slv = NDSolveValue[{D[sigma*D[u[x, y], x], x] +D[sigma*D[u[x, y], y], y] == 0,DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 19, y == 0.15], DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]}, u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

The solution can be easily obtained. Just try. The solution takes a few minutes.

If, however, I do the same trick as above and solve it simultaneously for the potential, u(x,y), and for the currents, v1(x,y) and v2(x,y):

```
sigma = If[ElementMarker == 1, 1000000, 1];
slv2 = NDSolveValue[{D[sigma*D[u[x, y], x], x] + 
     D[sigma*D[u[x, y], y], y] == 0, v2[x, y] == sigma*D[u[x, y], x], 
   v3[x, y] == sigma*D[u[x, y], y], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 19, y == 0.15], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]}, {u[x, y], v2[x, y], 
   v3[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

After some time (about 10 minutes) Mma stops calculating and (I think) quits the kernel. All variables turn blue. Mma forgets everything.

So, can I do something about it?

Comment: Are you running out of memory?

Comment: Mma is a toy,use Matlab.;-)

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Probably, it looks so, but I do not know.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Well, in Matlab I am illiterate. I might try Comsol, but there I guess I will have problems in creating the domain.

Comment: I ran your problem on my 16 GB, 4 processor PC with a 100 GB SSD.  It twice ran out of memory at 12 GB (other programs were using the rest), copying material to the SSD in order to continue.  Just now the kernel crashed.  Probably, you need to use a somewhat smaller mesh.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, I only saw this now, is this still a problem? I am not able to download the list from dropbox.

Comment: @user21 No, thank you. I have already succeeded with this problem, and presently am working on other things. Thank you for your readiness to help.